# Get UTC epoch time till start of current year in C++

Tags: c++, time, epoch, c++-chrono

I'm trying to get EPOCH time (universal time without region difference) at start of the current year. Below is what I wrote:

```
    time_t getEpochTimeAtSOY(){
        /* Get the current year */
        time_t currTime = time(NULL);
        struct tm *aTime = localtime(&currTime);
        int currentYear = aTime->tm_year;   // This is (actualCurrentYear - 1900), so 2020 - 1900 = 120

        /* Now find out EPOCH time for start of currentYear */
        struct tm t;
        time_t timeSinceEpoch = 0;
        memset (&t, 0, sizeof(t));  // Initalize to all 0's
        t.tm_year = currentYear;
        t.tm_mday = 1;

        timeSinceEpoch = timegm(&t); // EPOCH time of 1st Jan <currentYear> 00:00

        return (timeSinceEpoch);
    }
```

This returns correct result (ie. 1577836800) on x86 or x86_64, but the target board (cross compiler) doesn't support timegm() function. If I use mktime() inplace of timegm(), it results in region time difference. Can someone please suggest an alternative portable solution? Maybe using std::chrono  or something else?

Answer (score 3):

I just realized that `getEpochTimeFromSOY()` is intended to just return the `time_t` associated with the first of the year, and not do the subtraction between the current time and the first of the year.  Here's that:

```
std::time_t
getEpochTimeFromSOY()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto currTime = system_clock::now();
    auto y = year_month_day{floor<days>(currTime)}.year();
    return floor<seconds>(sys_days{y/1/1} - sys_days{})/1s;
}
```

---

This is very easy in C++20, and there is a library to do it with C++20 syntax that works back to C++11 (using chrono).

Here's the C++20 syntax:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

std::time_t
getEpochTimeFromSOY()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto currTime = system_clock::now();
    auto y = year_month_day{floor<days>(currTime)}.year();
    return floor<seconds>(currTime - sys_days{y/1/1})/1s;
}
```

[Here's the header-only, free, open-source library that you can use prior to C++20](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date), and here is the syntax for using it:

```
#include "date/date.h"

#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

std::time_t
getEpochTimeFromSOY()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto currTime = system_clock::now();
    auto y = year_month_day{floor<days>(currTime)}.year();
    return floor<seconds>(currTime - sys_days{y/1/1})/1s;
}
```

I.e. include `date.h` and add `using namespace date`.

Explanation of the code:

- Get the current time as a `system_clock::time_point`.
- Get the year of the current time in UTC.
- Subtract the first instant of the year (UTC) from the current time, truncate it to seconds precision, and extract the count by dividing by 1 second.

The syntax `1s` was introduced in C++14.  In C++11 you can change that to `seconds{1}`.  Or you can replace `/1s` with `.count()` to extract the seconds as an integral type.

If you would rather not use a free, open-source library to do this, you can grab the [underlying algorithms from here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html) and code it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

[ Note: this is more of a "design meta-answer". Howard's answer is correct - and I have upvoted it. ]

If I were writing this code, I would instead write two functions `getCurrentYear()` and `epochTimeAtStartOfYear(year y)`.  Each does a single thing, and can be combined to do what you want, but they also can be used in other contexts.

(Warning - untested code)

```
std::chrono::year
getCurrentYear()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return year_month_day{floor<days>(system_clock::now())}.year();
}

std::time_t
getEpochTimeFromSOY(std::chrono::year y)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return floor<seconds>(sys_days{y/1/1} - sys_days{})/1s;
}

std::time_t getEpochTimeAtSOY()
{
    return getEpochTimeFromSOY(getCurrentYear());
}
```